# DRUPAL: customize CCK fields order for a subset of nodes (belonging to the same content type)

Tags: drupal

I'm using a Drupal content type for all my nodes.

I was wondering if I can drag and drop (or just change the order of the CCK fields for some projects without having to create a new content type for the different projects.

For example, my customer would like to swap a CCK Image_field with a CCK Text_area for some particular projects. Is there a way to avoid to create a new content type just for these few changes ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A content type has a fixed field order. If you would like to alter it, you will need to create a new content type. The only modifications that are made "on the fly" are fields that are empty (such as an image field without an uploaded image), in which case they're just not shown in the view.